# Remotely stopping website in IIS7 on Windows 2008 via command line?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, command-line-interface

How do I remotely stop a website in IIS7, in Windows 2008, via command line?

Answer (score 3):

IISReset takes a computer name:

```
IISReset <Computer> -Stop
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of by using a command line would be to use Powershell remoting and issue the standard iisreset /stop

If you can not use powershell, look at sysinternals PsExec - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

This will allow you to use iisreset /stop remotely.

If you do not want either of these two, you can always do it via the gui - download the admin tools - http://www.iis.net/extensions/AdministrationPack - and right click the computer object, type the computer name and then stop/restart from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from a remote command line, you could use [Microsoft/Sysinternal's PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and issue this command:

```
iisreset -stop
```

If you want to do that for individual sites, you could use the appcmd tool which was introduced in IIS 7:

```
appcmd stop site <identifier>
```

This could also be interesting for remote administration of IIS 7:

[Remote Administration for IIS Manager](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/) (on learn.iis.net)